# projection and EPSG mismatch when buffering a geometry

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-6

as shown in the code posted below, i am using `turf.js` to buffer a geometry in the listener callback of `modifyend` of `Modify` event.
i tried to set the buffered feature `asOLFeature` on the map via: `this.#vectorSource.addFeature(asOLFeature)`

to assure that the buffered geometry is placed on the map, i converted `asOLFeature.getGeometry()` to geojson format so i can visualize it.
the code i used to convert the `OL Geometry` to `GeoJSON` is as follows:

```
var writer = new GeoJSON();
var geoJsonStr = writer.writeGeometry(asOLFeature.getGeometry());
```

the digitized geometry is shown in image-1 below, and the buffered geometry is shown in image-2 below.

Apparently, the digitized geometry in image-1 when gets buffered using  `turf`, as shown in image-2, it somehow gets converted into two geometries and displaced.

i believe it about coordinate transformation and projection issue, but i do not know how to solve it.

**code**

```
this.#modifyEvtNullifierFeature = evt.feature;
const modifyEvtNullifierAsGeom = this.#modifyEvtNullifierFeature.getGeometry();
const geojsonFormat = new GeoJSON();
const geosonGeometry = geojsonFormat.writeGeometryObject(modifyEvtNullifierAsGeom, {
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
    dataProjection:'EPSG:4326'
  });
let geomInMercator = turf.toMercator(geosonGeometry);
const buffered = turf.buffer(geomInMercator, 60, {units: 'kilometers'});
let bufferedInWgs84 = turf.toWgs84(buffered);
const asOLFeature = geojsonFormat.readFeature(bufferedInWgs84, {
    dataProjection:'EPSG:4326',
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
  });
this.#modifyEvtNullifierFeature.set(ModifyEvtNullifierFeaturesConstants.CONST_IS_MODIFY_EVT_NULLIFIER_FEATURE.description, true);
this.#vectorSource.addFeature(asOLFeature);
```

**image-1**
[image]

**image-2**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turf.js expects WGS84 coordinates.  If you are using Openlayers to transform between projections you do not need to reverse that with toMercator/toWgs84

```
const geosonGeometry = geojsonFormat.writeGeometryObject(modifyEvtNullifierAsGeom, {
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
    dataProjection:'EPSG:4326'
  });
const buffered = turf.buffer(geosonGeometry, 60, {units: 'kilometers'});
const asOLFeature = geojsonFormat.readFeature(buffered, {
    dataProjection:'EPSG:4326',
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
  });
```